# GLSL loop array indexing not working on ATI?

Tags: glsl, ati

I have a simple loop in GLSL to compute a bezier curve, and it works flawlessly on NVidia hardware.
However, it crashes on ATI cards, even though I am using version 1.20, which, IIRC, introduced non const array access.
I tried with later version (1.3 and 1.5) but still no luck.

If I unroll my loop, the code works again.
What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you post some code illustrating the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I posted this yesterday night, and was completely exhausted. Cant't edit question, damn. Well it appeared the problem had nothing to do with loop array indexing, the array in question is a uniform, and when I setUniform i raise a gl error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a driver bug (probably fixed by now, but I'm not sure).

Relevant reading: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=280190&page=1